# I find an error Cannot read property 'renderError' of null at fallbackResult

Tags: javascript, render, fallback

I found an error
cannot read property `renderError` of null at fallbackResult  while executing below code

```
import makeups from './makeups.js';

class DataSource {
    static makeup(keyword) {
        return fetch(`http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json?product_type=${keyword}`)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(responseJson => {
                if(responseJson.arrray) {
                    return Promise.resolve(responseJson.array);
                } else {
                    return Promise.reject(`${keyword} is not found`)
                }
           })
    }
}
export default DataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

[this a error ini browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXZA0.png)

import makeups from './makeups.js';

class DataSource {
    static makeup(keyword) {
        return fetch(`http://makeup-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products.json?product_type=${keyword}`)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(responseJson => {
                if(responseJson.arrray) {
                    return Promise.resolve(responseJson.array);
                } else {
                    return Promise.reject(`${keyword} is not found`)
                }
            })
    }
}

export default DataSource;

Answer (score -1):

Try to check in index.html espescially in web component you must change it if you change your const name, file name, and etc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOzR6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFfDB.png)

It works for me, but the other challenge is the API won't load data source and i can't figure it what.